# Getting this category.php to display a certain category! (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to get a PAGE to display a certain category. This particular page is "Ideas and thoughts"

I want to write a few lines about my ideas and thoughts, and under it, display the CATEGORY with ID 16 named "Thoughts"

How would I go about?

Here is my themes category.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="wrap">
<!-- Main Content-->
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/content-top.gif" alt="content top" class="content-wrap" />
    <div id="content">
        <!-- Start Main Window -->
        <div id="main">
            <?php global $query_string; $catnum_posts = get_option('theme_catnum_posts') ;
        query_posts($query_string . "&showposts=$catnum_posts&paged=$paged&cat=$cat"); ?>
            <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/entry.php'); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

                <?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); }
                else { ?>
                    <?php include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/navigation.php'); ?>
                <?php } ?>

            <?php else : ?>
                <?php include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/no-results.php'); ?>
            <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
        </div>
        <!-- End Main -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

I tried to change:

```
query_posts($query_string . "&showposts=$catnum_posts&paged=$paged&cat=$cat"); ?>
```

to

```
query_posts($query_string . "&showposts=$catnum_posts&paged=$paged&cat=16"); ?>
```

However it didn't work..

Any ideas?

Comment: What is $query_string resolving to? Also, if you have any other queries before this one you will need to do wp_reset_query() before query_posts()

Answer (score 0):

The global `$query_string` on a category page has almost certainly already defined the `cat` argument, which might be why its ignoring your `cat=16`. I would also do a fresh `query_posts` by following Kai's advice and calling `wp_reset_query`. Try this loop:

```
<?php $catnum_posts = get_option('theme_catnum_posts') ;
    wp_reset_query();
    $cat = 16;
    query_posts("&showposts=$catnum_posts&paged=$paged&cat=$cat"); ?>
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/entry.php'); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
```